# How can I redirect one missing image to the correct path, but only that specific image?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a wordpress + woocommerce site with one particular issue. We have an icon image (png) that appears in the product and from time to time it removes the absolute URL of the image to a relative one using ../ and it creates an invalid URL. I need to catch all calls to that specific image, no matter what URL it is, of course, only the 404 ones, and redirect it to the right path.
For example, the right image is:

```
    https://colmena.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/event-icon-xxs.png
```

And this is one of the wrong calls:

```
    https://colmena.co.il/shop/eventos/wellness/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/event-icon-xxs.png
```

I need the second one to redirect to the first one, but I cannot use the full wrong URL because it changes based on the categories and subcategories (the /shop/eventos/wellness part).

I tried a couple of catch all examples found here and elsewhere trying to adapt them, but I just made it worse so I removed them all.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is questionable if what you attempt really is a good idea. I personally would always prefer to fix the actual cause of the issue instead of trying to handle the symptom, as you suggest...

That said I assume the following is what you are actually looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?shop/(?:[^/]+)/(?:[^/]+)/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/event-icon-xxs\.png$ /wp-content/uploads/2021/01/event-icon-xxs.png [L]
```

I think however that you can simplify that, since you most likely do not use a similar path for other locations:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /?event-icon-xxs\.png$ /wp-content/uploads/2021/01/event-icon-xxs.png [L]
```

Comment: Hi. I tried both and neither worked. The first one should have worked because both segments with wildcards are the ones that will change depending on their categories, but so far it's not working.

Comment: Then most likely those rules do not get applied... Where have you implemented the rules? How did you make sure they are evaluated at all? Try to place an obvious syntax error into that definition and monitor your http server while restarting it and while making test requests. What do you observe?

Comment: I placed them in their own block, first before and then after the Wordpress block in htaccess. I have worked with redirects before but this one has me banging my head for several days already. I checked the logs and they are not being triggered nor other errors appear, which I guess means that there is something else causing issues before the rendering of that URL. Inspecting the elements I found that the URL being stored is not the complete / absolute URL but `../wp-content/uploads/2021/01/event-icon-xxs.png` and when trying to open it the wrong URL call occurs.

Comment: I cannot say where `../wp-content/uploads/2021/01/event-icon-xxs.png` points to, since I don't know your hierarchy. But that does not really matter in the end. What counts is the request that reaches the server. If that is to `/shop/eventos/wellness/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/event-icon-xxs.png` then above rules will get applied. _Unless_ some other rules get applied before that. Maybe there are rewriting rules in the real http server's host configuration? That will get applied before any distributed configuration files are considered. Above rule belongs _before_ the wp rewriting rules.

Comment: I you cannot get this to work you should start using rewrite logging to learn, what is actually going on inside your rewriting engine. Take a look into the documentation to find out how. That depends on the actual version of the apache http server you are using.

Comment: Than you very much @arkascha , I will try tomorrow the rewrite logging to see what's going on. I tried using the full URL and make a redirect and it didn't apply, so there is definitely something happening there. If I make a redirect for a normal page it works, but not with the images.